# Obd scanner requirements

Tags: vw, obd-ii, jetta

My 1998 vw Jetta just died in my garage. Does it have to be running while using a obd scanner or will the electrical system still show the fault codes?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The ODB scanner should read the codes, as long as the ignition is turned on and has power. If you disconnect the battery or remove the fuse so that the ECU (engine control unit) loses power, it will reset and the codes will be cleared.